# Eclipse RCP: Calling MessageDialog in start method freezes application

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, startup, freeze

I've encountered the following issue:

Plugin executes it's `public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception` methode.

Within this methode I call `MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Some dummy title", "Some dummy text");`

I can see the Message Box but after that the application freezes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Display` with `Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();`.
2. Use the `Shell` of the created `Display` for the MessageDialog.
3. Dispose the created `Display`

works fine